Simplify data repetitive frame names and variable names
I'm creating a data frame with data from 12 datasets: pbp_2020_novbid, pbp_2020_vbid_nodup, pbp_2020_total, pbp_2021_novbid, pbp_2021_vbid_nodup, pbp_2021_total, ...,pbp_2023_novbid, pbp_2023_vbid_nodup, pbp_2023_total
They are data from 2020-2023 and there are 3 types of them: novbid, vbid_nodup, total. The dataset names are repetitive, I was wondering how can I make the codes more succinct? Maybe create a function?
Year <- c(rep(2020:2023, each=3))

VBID <- c(rep(0:2, time=4))

Total_plan_number <- c(length(unique(pbp_2020_novbid$bid_id)), length(unique(pbp_2020_vbid_nodup$bid_id)), length(unique(pbp_2020_total$bid_id)),length(unique(pbp_2021_novbid$bid_id)), length(unique(pbp_2021_vbid_nodup$bid_id)), length(unique(pbp_2021_total$bid_id)),length(unique(pbp_2022_novbid$bid_id)), length(unique(pbp_2022_vbid_nodup$bid_id)), length(unique(pbp_2022_total$bid_id)),length(unique(pbp_2023_novbid$bid_id)), length(unique(pbp_2023_vbid_nodup$bid_id)), length(unique(pbp_2023_total$bid_id)))
df <- data.frame(Year, VBID, Total_plan_number)


Hi, @Jenn0804, it isn't very clear what do you want help with: consolidate the dfs, extract unique values, bind cols, maybe something else?

@AdrianoMello Hi, I was wondering how can I make the code more succinct because there are a lot of repetitive parts in the data set names.

Yes, you can!, but we need a practical case. Example: make your big df big_df from all dfs starting with "pbp" with big_df <- bind_rows(mget(ls(pattern = "^pbp"))).

Possible duplicate, How to make a list of data frames?. If you had the data frames in a list you would do Total_plan_number = sapply(list_of_data, \(x) length(unique(x$bid_id)))

As the comments suggest, you could dump all of those data frames into a list and then iterate over them. However, your existing setup could also be adapted as follows:
library(dplyr)

data.frame(Year, VBID) %>%
  mutate(
    Total_plan_number = sapply(
      paste("pbp", Year, VBID, sep = "_"),
      function(name) {
        length(unique(get(name)$bid_id))
      }
    )
  )

This is what it does:

generate the name of each data frame using paste() then
iterate over the names with sapply() and
for each name retrieve the corresponding data frame using get() and
remove duplicates from the bid_id column and count.

Here's the result using some test data:
   Year       VBID Total_plan_number
1  2020     novbid                 5
2  2020 vbid_nodup                 7
3  2020      total                 5
4  2021     novbid                 9
5  2021 vbid_nodup                 5
6  2021      total                11
7  2022     novbid                13
8  2022 vbid_nodup                 3
9  2022      total                 5
10 2023     novbid                12
11 2023 vbid_nodup                 9
12 2023      total                 5

